# How are characters converted from Dark Heresy 1st to 2nd edition?

Tags: conversion, player-characters, dark-heresy-2e, dark-heresy-1e

Is it possible to convert characters from previous edition to current one? How is it achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Officially, there isn't

The DH2e core rules and supplements do not provide any information on converting a 1e character to 2e.

### In practice, there are a few methods you can try

- Make a new character using the same XP total. Buy talents, skills, and characteristics as you see fit. The XP values between the systems are generally similar and should produce a character of roughly the same ability (albeit with a bit more freedom as DH2e is open-ended in its advancement options). Find similar/equivalent gear in DH2e and give that to the character. If no such gear exists, just check to make sure that the item isn't at odds with anything in DH2e and use it as its written in 1e (there shouldn't be such a thing, the editions are remarkably similar).
- Determine the Homeworld, Background, and Role that most closely fits your character. Then go through the DH1e character and note the equivalent DH2e version of those talents/skills/characteristic advances. Use the same initial characteristics as your DH1e character and determine the amount of XP it would cost to buy those skills, talents, and characteristic advances. Compare across all characters and bring the others into line (as some certainly will have spent more XP than others). As above, give DH2e equivelant gear to the character.